# Add additional server parameters to Datatables from a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've developed a plugin for adding new features to Datatables 1.9 which has been working fine client side. I now need it to work server side by adding additional parameters to aoData. I've tried pushing them on and redrawing.

My code looks something like

```
 $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.customFilter = function(oSettings, filter) { 
      oSettings.aoServerParams.push({"name":"filter", "value":filter});
      oSettings.oInstance.fnDraw();   
 }
```

The server is reprocessing but the new params are not available on aoData or aoServerParams
//Added fnDraw() code from davidkonrad

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. How do you call `customFilter`? Can you setup a fiddle that produces the error?

Comment: I might be able to setup a fiddle after I strip a lot out. It's called as part of a plugin that is added to the table through the sdom property.

Comment: I would try using `oSettings.oInstance.fnDraw()` instead ... This is always present, cannot know why `this.fnDraw()` is undefined (it should not be so)

Comment: Thanks that's working, what's not working is the param is not available on aoData in the fnServerData() callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in DataTables 1.9 to push additional parameters on to aoData for server side processing *from a plugin* you must push a closure. *Not* just the parameters.

```
oSettings.aoServerParams.push({
    "fn": function(aoData) {             
        aoData.push({"name": "filter", "value": filter});
     },
     "sName": "addParams"
});
```